# What is the difference between these object indexing methods in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use as.Date() on my data set but don't understand the difference between two methods of indexing my data.

This is my data (test2.csv):

```
Date        Aadfe   Wee     Dell    Percent
10/11/2012  1211    1000    3556    0.03
10/12/2012  100     2000    3221    0.43
10/13/2012  3423    10000   2343    0.54
10/14/2012  10000   3000    332     0.43
10/15/2012  2342    500     4435    0.43
10/16/2012  2342    800     2342    0.23
10/17/2012  2342    1500    1231    0.12
10/18/2012  111     2300    333 
10/19/2012  1231    1313    3433    
10/20/2012  3453    5654    222 
10/21/2012  3453    3453    454 
10/22/2012  5654    7685    3452
```

My code:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("test2.csv")
new <- c(data["Date"])
newDates <- as.Date(new, "%m/%d/%Y")
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.character(newDates), y = Percent)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

I get this error:

```
Error in as.Date.default(new, "%m/%d/%Y") : 
  do not know how to convert 'new' to class “Date”
```

Yet when I try

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- read.csv("test2.csv")
new <- data$Date
newDates <- as.Date(new, "%m/%d/%Y")
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.character(newDates), y = Percent)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3)
```

The plot is fine and there is no error. My question is: What is the difference between data$Date and c(data["Date"])? When printing them in the terminal, they both give a similar result. I need to use c(data["Date"]) because I'm working under the assumption that I don't know the column name of the data, so I cannot directly use data$Date. In my actual program the column name will be an input from the user, so my code would actually be c(data[input$x]). I was using c(data["Date"]) as a test.

Comment: I believe you want `data[["Date"]]`; have a look at `str(new)` rather than printing to the console, it is possible that `c()` does some coercion.

Comment: Please read and re-read @Dirk's answer to your previous question, as well as his comment again.

Comment: @baptiste: very nice, this is exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: Also: use `lubridate` to handle your dates (esp if you are already using `ggplot2`), it makes your life easier.

Comment: what's inside `aes` or `aes_string` should refer to variables in `data`, not free variables in the workspace.

Comment: great, I'm answering to a deleted question

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a bit greedy of me to post another question, so I took it off. here it is: Can I also ask: if I wanted to plot with aes_string instead of aes because of user-defined string inputs, how can I make this work with aes_string? As in aes_string(x=as.character(newDates), y = "Percent")). right now the x paramter is botched. Does this warrant another post?

Comment: I cannot tell. I offered an answer yesterday describing how to use `aes_string`. If you describe your efforts at searching and post your failed efforts people will know you are trying _and_ will elicit better advice. (Deleting posts is really not appropriate unless it was so simple or trivial that no one would benefit by looking at the answers.)

Comment: Why are you converting a vector of dates to character? That seems like a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

Credits to baptiste,

I needed to do

```
data[["Date"]]
```